# Send a text message Using FCM and Twilio

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio

I want to send a text message to a particular user's number stored in Firebase Database. For that I have Used FCM and Twilio. My problem is that I got following errors. (Follwed tutorial from  https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sms-texting-with-twilio/)

```js
errrrror { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.twilio.com api.twilio.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.twilio.com',
  host: 'api.twilio.com',
  port: 443 }
```

Comment: You could've found the answer to this very question doing a light Google search. This being said, it seems like you need to purchase premium services to call 3rd party software from firebase - [link](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/292)

Comment: Thank for your kind information.

Answer (score 0):

Your country block twilio ,you can use proxy before you send a request to twilio.in english you can deploy your project on a external server in another country

Comment: I don't think you can tell that from the error that was posted. Also, I don't know of any countries that block Twilio.

Comment: you can try  heroku for example to deploy your app and then you will see it is working